# Confuse about Object.create in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

Suppose I have an object, and create another object with it:

```
var person = {
    name: "Lee",
    age: "12",
    others: {}
}

var per1 = Object.create(person);
var per2 = Object.create(person);

per2.name = "Mike";
per2.others.hello = "world";

console.log(per1); // Object {name: "Lee", age: "12", obj: Object}
console.log(per2); // Object {name: "Mike", name: "Lee", age: "12", obj: Object}

console.log(per1.others.hello, per2.others.hello) // world world
```

my confuse is:

- Why the `per2` have double name? If another is from prototype, I try to `per2.prototype.name = "mike"` it tell me the prototype is undefined, but how can that is undefined? The job of `Object.create` isn't `Creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties.` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)
- Why the `others` would shared between `per1` and `per2` but the name doesn't

Another confuse is suppose I have a function:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name
}
Person.prototype.say = function () {
    console.log("hello")
}
```

but create an other object from the function, no the prototype of the function:

```
var obj = Object.create(Person);

console.log(obj) // Function {}:
console.log(obj.prototype) // undefined
```

Why the prototype is undefined? Doesn't the `Object.create` create it?

### Update:

As @bfavaretto said only the constructor can have `prototype`, and the `Object.getPrototypeOf` can show one object's prototype.So I tried these two approach to get the `per1`'s prototype:

```
console.log(per1.constructor.prototype) // Object{}
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(per1)) //Object {name: "Lee", age: "12", obj: Object}
```

they are different, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Object.create` returns a new object whose [[Prototype]] is the object passed as an argument. So both `per1` and `per2` share the same prototype.

Now, some facts about prototype objects:

- When you try to read a property and the object doesn't have it, it will look for it up the prototype chain. So if you `console.log(per1.name)`, 'name' is not found on `per1`, but on its prototype.
- However when you try to write to a non-existing property, it's just created, on the object itself, not its prototype. So `per2.name = "Mike";` creates a new 'name' property on `per2`, and that shadows the one from the prototype. For some reason the Chrome console decided to log both, but for practical use only "Mike" is readable.

The above is supposed to answer your first question. The second one is related, but also have to do with the way objects work in js. `person.others` is an object. `per2.others` is a reference to that exact object. The same reference is shared by `per1`, that's why you see "world" twice. That didn't happen with "name" because it's a string, a primitive value, unlike `others`.

To answer your last question: only functions (constructors) have a `prototype` property. Objects created with `new Person` inherit from  `Person.prototype`, but theyir prototype object is only reachable via the non-standard `obj.__proto__` or `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` (which is not supported on older browsers).

Comment: The new object which `object.create` return is the reference of the argument or the copy of the argument? I think it must be the reference, if not, how the `per1` and `per2` share the same `others`, am I right?

Comment: Go ahead with waht you said, I have another confuse just as I have update the question

Comment: @hh54188 I saw your update. You used `Object.create` and passed an object literal to it, so `per1.constructor` is the `Object` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`thing.prototype` isn't a thing's prototype. I don't know if standard ECMAScript provides any way to access an object's prototype, but `thing.__proto__` tends to work.

For functions, `f.prototype` is the prototype of anything created with `new f()`. When I try your `Object.create(Person);` thing, it seems to work:

```
console.log(obj.prototype)
>Person {say: function}
// prototype property inherited from Person function
```

Perhaps you were doing this in the Chrome Javascript console, and you were confused by `undefined` showing up after the actual logging result. That's the return value of the `console.log` call.

Comment: Standard way is [`Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) - note that this one is non-writable. `__proto__` is probably coming in the next spec and is supported even in IE11 anyway.